# Gremlin query to search across vertices for a substring

Tags: gremlin

I have a graph in which I run the following commands and obtain the below results:

```
gremlin> g.V().has("ip") //Query 1
==>v[127.0.0.11]
==>v[127.0.0.22]
==>v[127.0.0.33]

gremlin> g.V().has("mac") //Query 2
==>v[AA:BB:CC:00:11:FF]
==>v[A2:B2:C2:00:12:F2]
==>v[A3:B3:C3:00:13:F3]

gremlin> g.V().has("ip",like("*11*")) //Query 3
==>v[127.0.0.11]

gremlin> g.V().has("mac",like("*11*")) //Query 4
==>v[AA:BB:CC:00:11:FF]

gremlin> g.V().has("ip").or().has("macAddr") //Query 5
==>v[127.0.0.11]
==>v[127.0.0.22]
==>v[127.0.0.33]
==>v[AA:BB:CC:00:11:FF]
==>v[A2:B2:C2:00:12:F2]
==>v[A3:B3:C3:00:13:F3]

gremlin> g.V().union(has("ip"),has("macAddr")) //Query 6
==>v[127.0.0.11]
==>v[127.0.0.22]
==>v[127.0.0.33]
==>v[AA:BB:CC:00:11:FF]
==>v[A2:B2:C2:00:12:F2]
==>v[A3:B3:C3:00:13:F3]
```

I have a requirement where I want to search through both "mac" and "ip" for a given search term.
I tried the following two queries but only got back the same results as Query 5 and Query 6. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
g.V().has("ip",like("*11*")).or().has("macAddr",like("*11*")) 

g.V().union(has("ip",like("*11*")),has("macAddr",like("*11*")))
```

Comment: your use of `or()` in your question seemed right to me, but you say that gives the wrong answer. what graph are you using?

Comment: It's a Cassandra instance which we're querying using gremlin.

Comment: meaning, you're using JanusGraph?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after a lot of trial and error (probably should've been my first step, but anyway).
The required solution can be obtained by including the `g.V()` inside the union like so:

`g.V().union(g.V().has("ip",like("*11*")),g.V()has("macAddr",like("*11*")))`

Comment: this might work, but it is a nonstandard usage of `g` to spawn traversals into another traversal. i'm wondering why that even works the way that it does actually. perhaps we can get to the real root of the problem, as the approach you present here doesn't seem ideal and may be "fixed" in another version.